# TShape and Integer Value

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle

I'm recently working on an *Dart-Counter*. 
I have a Dartboard presented on a `TImage` and for every counting position there is a `TShape`.

Is it possible to assigne a value to a `TShape`, because the `TShape` does not like integer?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`Tag`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TComponent.Tag) property to store your integer value, if nothing else is using that property.

> `Tag` has no predefined meaning. The `Tag` property can store any additional integer value for the convenience of developers.

Another way would be to derive a sub-class of `TShape` and add a property to store the information. This would allow you to give the property a more meaningful name, and make the intent clear.

I would comment though that building up a complex visual user interface out of `TShape` objects is perhaps an inefficient and error prone way to go about your task. Usually for a task like this is would be better to make a custom control that painted itself appropriately, without the use of sub-components.